# Implementing google+ sign in button to localhost with google API

Tags: html, button, google-api, google-plus, google-api-client

I am trying to implement the Google+ log in /sign in button on a website I'm coding through Sublime Text2 and running through Apache. I'm VERY new to web development and using localhost / http://127.0.0.1 .

So my questions comes in because when I have the button in the "index" Chrome HTML Document, it runs fine and I can log in with my google+ account.

BUT, if I have the button in a webpage linked to it (a new document "signin" Chrome HTML Document) the log in does not go through. It will pull up my accounts but it won't let me log in completely.

ERROR Error: origin_mismatch

I think I have to change something in my JavaScript Origins in my Credentials in my API's and Auth, but it won't let me add something like http://localhost/signin.html   It says

```
Origins URIs must not contain a path: http://localhost/signin.html
```

How can I give this webpage access??

Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

What was happening to me was that the UX on the redirect URI / authorized origin was confusing me and the "save" button wasn't working. Just because the item has been added to the list, doesn't mean it has been saved. Also, ensure you've added the correct port if it is non-standard.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was my issue. In my case I was clicking save but not pressing enter to add it to the list.

Answer (score 7):

> Origins URIs must not contain a path: http://localhost/signin.html

`http://localhost/signin.html` without a path becomes `http://localhost`. You must edit your application in the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) so that it does not have a path.